# How to show htmlString into webview? The html string contains bootstrap image

Tags: ios, swift, webview

The HTML string is:

```
<p> Business Name and City Located In <i class=\"fa fa-check\"></i></p>\r\n
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let webview = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))

let htmlString = "<p> Business Name and City Located In <i class=\"fa fa-check\"></i></p>\r\n"
let fontAwesomeHtml = """
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">\(htmlString)
"""
webview.loadHTMLString(fontAwesomeHtml, baseURL: nil)
view.addSubview(webview)
```

Screenshot of result:

[image]